Problem at detecting network connections
I made a fully exchange of disks, like taken from another computer, to my computer. It boots up, everything works fine, except that i run nmcli d wifi list and nothing shows up.
I connected an ethernet cable to see if it was wifi or internet at all, but i got nothing.
A'm afraid that with the exchange of disks, something went wrong. would you help me out please?

Can't help you without details of your system, what hardware you have, etc.  Including the output of sudo lspci among other things.

I've moved disks from one failed computer to another of the same make/model & had issues, yet moved a drive from one system to a different make/model and its perfect...   We don't know what Ubuntu product/release you're using, so we don't yet have details as to what you're asking about. Many defaults are set at install time (from install media) so being specific may also help.

If you can, add a bit more detail to your question. What WiFi hardware and/or laptop model are you using? Are there any error messages in the output of sudo dmesg or other info relevant to WiFi or networking? What is the output of lspci? Can you ping other hosts on your network (try by IP address only first)?
